# unable to refer app module classes in dynamic feature module when running unit test cases

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps, dynamic-feature

Our project has dynamic feature module with a dependency on the app module. The classes in the dynamic feature module have a dependency on app module.

We also have unit test cases in the dynamic module testing individual classes of the dynamic module. The unit tests run fine when run through android studio. Got an error running unit tests using gradlew.

Below is the error:

./gradlew :dynamic_feature1:testDebugUnitTest
Getting the following error:

````
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.example.dynamic_feature1.DynamicPresenterTest > testXyz FAILED
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/dynamicfeature/AppBase
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
15:40:13.225 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)```
````

Comment: created an issue on google issue tracker:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132906456

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/dynamicfeature/AppBase` issue, try this command:

```
./gradlew test
```

see  [Android jUnit Test java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844600/android-junit-test-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-database-sqlite-sqlit/42845661#42845661)